# update $scope variable after factory get call

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am new to angular. I am using code as:

**factory** :

```
// Factory
module.factory('mainJsonData', function($http) {
 var promise = null;
  return function() {
   if (promise) {
    // If we've already asked for this data once,
    // return the promise that already exists.
    return promise;
   } else {
    promise = $http.get('json/main.json');
    return promise;
   }
 };
});
```

and **controller** code is :

```
// Getting factory data
 mainJsonData().success(function(mainJsonData) {
  $scope.mainJsonData = mainJsonData;
 });
```

I want to use `$scope.mainJsonData` in custom directive.

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? you want to pass `$scope.mainJsonData` to custom directive ?

Comment: Other than using the [deprecated `success` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice), I can't see any problems so far. Where's the rest of your code that you are having problems with?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      mainJsonData: '=mainJsonData
    },
  };
});
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
   mainJsonData().success(function(mainJsonData) {
      $scope.mainJsonData = mainJsonData;
   });
});
```

**main.html**

```
<div ng-controller="myController">

   <data-my-dir main-json-data="mainJsonData">
   </data-my-dir>

</div>
```

So that you can access `mainJsonData` in your directive using $scope.